# How to get first element from observable and return an observable for the rest of the stream?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive

I'm trying to write an Observable to return objects from something like a CSV file. My problem is that I want to use the header of the file, to use as property names for the next elements of the Observer. For example, if I have this CSV:

```
symbol;word
1;one
2;two
3;three
```

I want this to happen:

```
getObjects().subscribe(o => console.log(o));

// should log this:
{ symbol: '1', word: 'one' }
{ symbol: '2', word: 'two' }
{ symbol: '3', word: 'three' }
```

I managed to do this with this code:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
const _zipObject = require('lodash/zipObject');

const getObjects = () => {
    const observable = Rx.Observable.of(
        ['symbol', 'word'],
        ['1', 'one'],
        ['2', 'two'],
        ['3', 'three']
    ).share();

    let header;

    return Rx.Observable.concat(
        observable.first().do(line => header = line).filter(() => false),
        observable.skip(1).map(line => _zipObject(header, line))
    );
};

getObjects().subscribe(o => console.log(o));
```

It works, but doesn't feel nice. I also thought about using filter, for filtering the first element and setting the header, but it wouldn't feel much better, and would have the disadvantage of having the filter callback being called for every element.

Comment: This question describes clearly what I was also looking for. Why was it downrated?

Comment: @Aki I'm not sure also.. I think I was a victim of revenge-downvoting after discussing with someone in some other question.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `combineLatest` to get the header and date at the same time and avoid accessing it from the parent scope:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
const Observable = Rx.Observable;

const getObjects = () => {
    const observable = Observable.of(
        ['symbol', 'word'],
        ['1', 'one'],
        ['2', 'two'],
        ['3', 'three']
    ).share();

    const header$ = observable.take(1);
    const data$ = observable.skip(1);

    return Observable.combineLatest(header$, data$, (headers, line) => {
        const result = {};
        headers.forEach((header, i) => {
            result[header] = line[i];
        });

        return result;
    });
};

getObjects().subscribe(o => console.log(o));
```

This prints:

```
{ symbol: '1', word: 'one' }
{ symbol: '2', word: 'two' }
{ symbol: '3', word: 'three' }
```